# Using an intersection type which covers part of the union

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**Question:** Currently I have defined a function prop which takes in a parameter of type `TypeA | TypeB`. Then, I pass in a function which takes a parameter of type  `Type C & Type D` such that the intersection in fact has all the properties of `TypeA`.
However, I am getting the error that types are not compatible.

*(specific code below)*

```
//Types//
export interface IMatchingLocationItem extends LocationResultType {
      displayTitle: string;
}
export interface SearchMenuItem {
  displayTitle: string;
  geo_id: string;
  administrative_area_level_1: string;
  administrative_area_level_2: string;
}
export type LocationResultType = {
  administrative_area_level_1: string;
  administrative_area_level_2: string;
  state_name: string;
  state_code: string;
  geo_id: string;
};

//prop function type
onItemClick: (item: IMatchingLocationItem | SearchMenuItem) => void;
//given imcompatible function type
const handleSearchItemClick = (location: LocationResultType & { displayTitle: string }) => void;
```

Comment: I’m not fully understanding that situation but it sounds like you need an Omit and a generic.  Along the lines of function<T extends C | D>(first: T, remaining: Omit<A, T>).  Remaining requires the properties of A which are not present in first.

Comment: pls share reproducable example

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, argument types should be covariant and the type of `item` should extend the type of `location`

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAqE8AcFMGcQFDQB6QPYCcAuACAlgHZbQYBmAhgMbQ4CSAsuVpQBaEDmAMmpU3mgVrEAtjhTECAE1g5uvLPwIAlOAFcANlggwcAbwQ5DRyXliR15cKDxZ10AFw5YWDBwDcCAL5JUmXIWIyKhoAZWhyDFZ6aAJVIWhRfUMTMwsrGztHZ1cCdg9Ddmg0AH08SSyXdwMccklhQlMXPgA3aGKI8OK7VvVigEYKnLzq2vqCRowWto7yLuge4oAmQarvFHRsfCISCmpZHj4BFVgNLSgaJJq6huyp9oxO7uhegadK3PyrsYm7mbmF5ZvIafZxMNoEcjCBxAqqGUHEYqUNCSaHZWE4QolMorD5eBAIECQDBoSA4UiqAiUBQCHBYc4IOy4ATxYQAYXUeEoAGtHAAKGwJRwMJisDhyQ6CEQAShwAF4AHw4ZpoMpynC8mUKvSeDwgdh4VoEfDCJHCSB8ABGdjJFKpilp9KRBGcOBY5CkdjCEVYLPZnK5at56gO1IIjnFoeOp20NAAZHocClzJZrLZUe92DhPJrFcrVbodfjmSI-dy1W6PdAvZEWL6OdyPEA)

or the following way)

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAqE8AcFMGcQFDQB6QPYCcAuACAlgHZbQYBmAhgMbQ4CSAsuVpQBaEDmAMmpU3mgVrEAtjhTECAE1g5uvLPwIAlOAFcANlggwcAbwQ5DRyXliR15cKDxZ10AFw5YWDBwDcCAL5JUmXIWIyKhoAZWhyDFZ6aAJVIWhRcRjpWR4+ARVYDS0oGn1DEzMLKxs7R2dXAnYPQ3ZoNAB9PElyl3cDHHJJYUJTFz4AN2gGiPCGuyH1BoBGVsrqjq6egj6MQeHR8nHoSYaAJjn27xR0bHwiEgpqVPlFTOztPMXu3or1kYwxiegp2ac2qo1TovFZvBRDD5fHY-faHQEdZxMYYEcjCBz-eZAxHEBqUNCSdEVdq1epNFoYo4IBAgSAYNCQHCkVQESgKAQ4LC5BB2XACeLCADC6jwlAA1o4ABQ2BKOBhMVgcOTpQQiHAAHxwYQiURicREAEocABeAB8OAGaGaxpwEsNpr0ng8IHYeCGBHwwjxwkgfAARnZGczWYoOVy8QRnDgWOQpHYtZEWPyhSLRdaJeo0myCI4lVn7ppHjgAGR6HCFcyWay2QkA9g4Tx2s0Wq26R1UvkiZNi63R2PQeOsJPCsUeIA)

Comment: It seems like both methods require the function onClick to take a parameter that requires more attributes then what I initially desired- is there a solution where the function can take SearchMenuItem, which is the smaller than IMatchingLocationItem?